# Eclipse. create aggregate maven task. Can eclipse-maven plugin it?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, eclipse-plugin, maven-eclipse-plugin

I have maven projects, opened in my Eclipse.

After each code changing I should to launch `task1`, `task2`, .... `taskN`.

Each task executes from different folder.

Is it possible to create task which would invoke `task1` then `task2` .... `taskN` ?

If `task45` ended in failure then from `task46` to `taskN` is not launch.

---

### UPDATE

I created aggregate task:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This feature does not seem to be supported by eclipse yet (Apr 2014). It is a known issue and a [ticket](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=39900) is already open for it.
However, you can have a look to the ["launch group"](http://wiki.eclipse.org/CDT/User/NewIn60#Debug_and_Launch) feature from the CDT plugin. It seems to be compatible with any launch configuration, including maven, and it should offer better control on sequantial execution of your tasks.

Comment: can you provide more information. how to install this DSF ? and where should I click?

Comment: CDT= C/C++ Development Tooling. You can have it in the eclipse marketplace (Help menu).